# Convert Excel formula to pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I'm trying to convert the following Excel formula for use in a pandas DataFrame:

=IFERROR(IFS(X3=TRUE,1,X2=TRUE,1),0)

I have a column in a pandas DataFrame (spray) that contains all TRUE or FALSE values.  I'm trying to convert the above formula so that a new column (SPRAY) shows a 1 when the data (spray) is TRUE, or it switches from TRUE to FALSE, but 0 otherwise.  For example:

```
spray     SPRAY
TRUE      1
FALSE     1
FALSE     0
TRUE      1
TRUE      1
TRUE      1
FALSE     1
FALSE     0
TRUE      1
TRUE      1
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
df["SPRAY"] = (df["spray"] | df["spray"].ne(df["spray"].shift())).astype(int)
```

Or as per @[*Hubert*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10263843/hubert), simply :

```
df["SPRAY"] = (df["spray"] | df["spray"].shift()).astype(int)
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   spray  SPRAY
0   True      1
1  False      1
2  False      0
3   True      1
4   True      1
5   True      1
6  False      1
7  False      0
8   True      1
9   True      1
```

Comment: df['SPRAY'] = (df['spray'] | df['spray'].shift()).astype(int)

Answer (score 0):

In the following, `np.where()` function is to check if the current value of the 'spray' column is True or if it is different from the value in the previous row. If either of these conditions is true, the corresponding value in the 'SPRAY' column is set to 1, otherwise, it is set to 0

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# create a sample dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'spray': [True, False, False, True, True, True, False, False, True, True]})

# use shift() to create a new column that contains the value of the previous row
df['previous_spray'] = df['spray'].shift(fill_value=False)

# use np.where() to apply the conditions of the original formula and return the corresponding values
df['SPRAY'] = np.where((df['spray'] == True) | (df['spray'] != df['previous_spray']), 1, 0)

# drop the 'previous_spray' column
df.drop(columns=['previous_spray'], inplace=True)

print(df)
```